# Configure ZSH to always fall back to path completion

Tags: zsh-completion

I'm using zsh, and the completions mostly just work.  But when I use various commands where an arbitrary command follows a command with specialized zsh handling, file path completions don't work.

```
# completes to 'npm run build' for a package.json with a 'build' script
npm run b<tab>
# does not complete the file path (to, say, `datafile/somefile.json`)
npm run build -- datafile/som<tab>
```

Obviously, npm has a configured completion definition that loads the package.json and understands valid args.  But after `--` the remaining args are just passed through, and I'd like file completion to be the default.

Is there a way to have zsh always fallback to path completion OR maybe have the `--` indicator commonly used to indicate end or arguments to turn back on default completions.